# drawing a flow chart to show system interactions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, flot

I have some transactional data in a oracle db and I need to know which is the best way to show this data as flowcharts on a webpage?

Sample Data in tables:::::
txn1|sourcesys
txn1|system1
txn1|system2
txn1|system3
txn1|endsys

I want to output this in a GUI as a flowchart diagram

sourcesys -----> system1 -----> system2 -----> system3 -----> endsys

I was thinking Angular JS with flot maybe? Can you please suggest a few simple ways to go about this? (only opensource libs please).

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You may use piechart for drawing a flow chart easily.
Reference link: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart